# Store more than default information in django-rest-framework-jwt

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am using Django version 1.8 and authentication with django-rest-framework-jwt.
After authentication, our application will return to front-end with information:

```
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

user.profile_picture = "test_profile_picture.jpg" #user is django.contrib.auth.models.User object
payload = jwt_payload_handler(user) 
token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)

 jwt_login_response = {
        "token": token
 }

return Response(jwt_login_response,status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

In front-end, we will decode by

```
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
var decodedToken = jwtDecode(token);
```

But at the moment decodedToken only contains value which seem default by django-rest-framework-jwt

```
Object {username: "test", user_id: 9, email: "test@gmail.com", exp: 1454754137}
```

I want to store more information in jwt like `profile_picture` but I don't know how. I really want to find a solution about this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override the payload that is attached to the token with the [`JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER` setting](http://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#jwt_payload_handler).

The default implementation includes the `username`, `user_id`, `email`, and `exp` (expiration time), as you've noticed. You can find the default implementation [on GitHub](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt/blob/df2a01c48dc0d7b804577cb9f94863b54a32d8de/rest_framework_jwt/utils.py#L10-L42).

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need is a custom user model. You can create this by creating a new Model with the fields you need and reference it to the Default User model via a One-One relationship.

This link might help - http://blog.mathandpencil.com/replacing-django-custom-user-models-in-an-existing-application/

Comment: I don't think their problem was with retrieving the data in Python, they've clearly got a method for getting the profile picture. JWT data can also be viewed in JS (or the JWT client), which is likely why they also want to include it.