# How do I include username (<str:username>) in my react native Endpoint

Tags: reactjs, django, react-native, django-rest-framework, jwt

Please im learning react native and I am stuck, my problem is that I need to be about to use something like this in my react native (API):

```
const endpoint = "/users/<username>/";

const getUser = () => client.get(endpoint);
```

So the gist is, I want to dynamically pass the user's username in there, because thats the only way to get the details from the backend (REST API), When i use POSTMAN and get this `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/*username*` it returns the needed data, but when I try that, even putting the username manually it doesnt work .

Secondly, is there a way to get the user's username from jwt token and pass it into the react native endpoint.

Id share my code below, Please bear with me:

API URL PATH IN DJANGO:

```
path('<str:username>/', profile_detail_api_view),
path('<str:username>/follow', profile_detail_api_view),
```

API CALL IN REACT NATIVE:

```
import client from "./client";

const endpoint = "/users/que/"; (FOR INSTANCE HERE IM PASSING THE USERNAME DIRECTLY TO TEST)

const getUser = () => client.get(endpoint);

export default {
  getUser,
};
```

PAYLOAD ON JWT SAMPLE:

```
{
  "token_type": "access",
  "exp": 1611483456,
  "jti": "47907077556234bd9b6a9fa330f5ee",
  "user_id": 2
}
```

I have tried a direct endpoint (blog) and it works, but that user part doesnt even though its the same url as how i used it in POSTMAN...

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239401/store-more-than-default-information-in-django-rest-framework-jwt) will answer your question.

Comment: THanks alot. Looking into it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Store more than default information in django-rest-framework-jwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35239401/store-more-than-default-information-in-django-rest-framework-jwt)

Comment: Yes. THanks. But this might seem silly, but where do i use the code? Settings or models?